# How to run Multiple test cases using python unittest and init method?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I try to develop calculator to for unittest
I try to run test cases using python unittest and init method.I always getting this error.

error:

---

AttributeError:'TestingClass' object has no attribute 'runTest'. Did you mean: 'subTest'?

---

I try to fix this error using renaming method name runTest. But it only works for one test case.I want to run multiple test case.So I want to help with that.How to run multiple test cases?

*this is my Calculator_test.py file*

***#This is the Phython Unit Testing Module***

import unittest

***#This is the class we want to test. So, we need to import it***

import Calculator_steps as CalculatorClass

class TestingClass(unittest.TestCase):

```
"""
The basic class that inherits unittest.TestCase
"""

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TestingClass, self).__init__()
    self.calculator = CalculatorClass.Calculator()
```

***#Requirment 1: Verify Calculator accepts only whole numbers.***

```
def runTest(self):
    with self.assertRaises(Exception):
        self.calculator.addNumbers('5.66,3.44')
```

***#Requirment 2: Verify Calculator does not accepts non numric values.***

```
def test_NonNumeric(self):
    with self.assertRaises(Exception):
        self.calculator.addNumbers('5,6,e')
```

*#This is my Calculator_steps.py file*

class Calculator:

```
def addNumbers(self,numberlist):
    total = ""
    return total
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the docs for how to run unit tests, https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#command-line-interface ,
Also please start the test function with `test_` prefix only then unittest will get to know it is a test.

Comment: This was very useful for the newbie like me.